# Value for UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey is zero when QuickType bar shows/hides. Why?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, uikeyboard, nsnotification

I use the `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` for changing my views when the keyboard is shown.

To animate along with the keyboard, I use the `NSNotification`'s user info dictionary to get the duration of the animation, with the `UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey` key.

This works for when the keyboard is shown and hidden. But not when its frame changes while it's already showing, e.g. when the QuickType bar is shown/hidden.

Anyone knows why this is the case? And how I should resolve this problem?